# List menu scrolling without IgnorePointer

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a menu list with `GridView`. But when I scroll, it fail because scroll inside listview hold parent element to scroll like this image

[image]

My issue is gone when I try to wrap my GridView inside `IgnorePointer`. But if I use `IgnorePointer` it is not allow me to click / tap my menu item.

How the best way to fix my issue?

My code (without `IgnorePointer`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: List.generate(
        menuItems.length,
        (index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showShortToast("Menu clicked " + index.toString());
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 70.0,
                  height: 70.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset(menuItems[index]["image"]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  menuItems[index]["text"],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the scroll in the grid view you can do as follows:

```
child: GridView.count(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Add physics
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          ...
```